# How make responsive table with a lot of field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I try to make responsive table with bootstraps with this table :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-dokumen">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 1</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 2</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 3</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 4</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 5</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 6</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 7</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 8</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 9</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 10</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 11</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 12</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 13</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 14</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 15</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 16</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 17</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 18</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 19</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan 20</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    //this is a value of table
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but the table always cross a line like this : [image: Example]

any suggestion if we have a lot of field in table and we want to make a responsive table?

Comment: You can add `overflow-x: auto;` to the parent wrapper of the table

Comment: Guess it's already as you are expecting - https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/mqvaNw

Comment: @DhavalJardosh You do realize that table isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try "table-responsive" class in `<table>` tag. It seems that you are working with data tables and bootstrap. Hopefully table-responsive class resolve your issue.